# Collapse multiple Parse Push notifications received into one

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to collapse multiple [Parse Push notifications](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/Android) into one. I looked into the `collapse_key` and I added it in the payload like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: somebody,
    collapse_key: "places_push",
    data: {
      alert: "alertText",
      type: "pushType"
    }
}//...
```

but multiple pushes are still not collapsing into one in my Android app(i.e. if I receive 2 push notifications in a row, I see two cards in the notification tray instead of 1). Should I handle this on the application side somehow (e.g. in the *onPushOpen* callback of **ParsePushBroadcastReceiver**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by overriding the *getNotification()* method of my subclass of **ParsePushBroadcastReceiver** and building there the notification with cumulative text (i.e. if there are already notifications being displayed, append to the text of those previous notifications the one received with the last Push). For allowing multiple lines into the notification, I set the style of the notification in the following way:

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Details: ");
for(String s: notificationLines){
    inboxStyle.addLine(s);
}
builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: could you please share the complete code that would be very appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the notification ID passed to your NotificationManager object stays the same for every message under the same collapse key. This way, your notification will simply get updated (instead of a new one getting displayed in addition to the previous ones). Refer to the `mNotificationManager.notify` code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating).